# Python3 - UnboundLocalError - referenced before assignment

Tags: python

Ok I've been hitting my head on this one for a while. I am trying to make a dynamic script to ssh to a range of ports through a menu.

Basics are menu, pick a closet, pick a switch, pick a port.

It seems to mostly work except when it tries to execute I get the error

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'port' referenced before assignment`

I put in a couple print lines for very basic debugging, and it does look like the right port is getting picked from the menu and returned, however it doesn't seem to be getting done at the right time or right order?

Results when running the code are below, and below that is my current code.

```
]$ console

Current Working Directory:  /app/network-scripts/oob

------------------------------ MENU ------------------------------
1. Data Center
2. IDF
0. Exit
___________________________________________________________________
Enter your Choice: 2
1 - idfA
2 - idfB
3 - idfC
4 - idfD
5 - idfE
6 - idfF
7 - idfG
8 - idfH
B. Go Back
X. Exit
Select Console Router [1-8]: 1
idfA

------------------------------ MENU ------------------------------
1. Switch A
2. Switch B
3. Switch C
4. VSwitch A
5. Vswitch B
B. Go Back
X. Exit
___________________________________________________________________
Enter your port choice [1-5]: 1
2002
password: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/console", line 139, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/bin/console", line 131, in main
    rlogin(host)
  File "/usr/local/bin/console", line 105, in rlogin
    port = port
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'port' referenced before assignment
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python36


import sys
import logging
import re
import os

from pexpect import pxssh
from getpass import getuser,getpass

os.chdir("/app/network-scripts/oob/")

username = getuser()


def first_menu():
    print()
    print("Current Working Directory: ", os.getcwd())
    print()

    print (30 * "-" , "MENU" , 30 * "-")
    print ("1. Data Center")
    print ("2. IDF")
    print ("0. Exit")
    print (67 * "_")


def idf_menu():
    devlist = []
    with open('obb-devs-idf','r') as devicesfile:
        i = 1
        d = 1
        hosts = devicesfile.readlines()
        for host in hosts: 
            print(i,"-",host,end='')
            i += 1
            devlist.append(host) 
        print("B. Go Back")
        print("X. Exit")
        d = input('{}{}{}'.format("Select Console Router [1-",i-1,"]: "))
        if d=="b":
            main()
        elif d=="x":
            print("Bye!")
            sys.exit()
        elif d.isdigit():
            selected = int(d) - 1
            host = devlist[selected] 
            return host
        else:
            print("Invalid Choice, try again")
            idf_menu()


def port_menu():
    print (30 * "-" , "MENU" , 30 * "-")
    print ("1. Switch A")
    print ("2. Switch B")
    print ("3. Switch C")
    print ("4. VSwitch A")
    print ("5. Vswitch B")
    print ("B. Go Back")
    print ("X. Exit")
    print (67 * "_")

    port = 0

    while True:
        choice = input("Enter your port choice [1-5]: ")
        if choice=="1":
            port = 2002
            return port
        elif choice=="2":
            port = 2003
            return port
        elif choice=="3":
            port = 2004
            return port
        elif choice=="4":
            port = 2010
            return port
        elif choice=="5":
            port = 2011
            return port
        elif choice=="b":
            main()
        elif choice=="x":
            print("Whatever! BYE!!")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            print("WRONG!!!!")
    return port


def rlogin(host):
    s = pxssh.pxssh()
    hostname = host
    username = getuser()
    password = getpass('password: ')
    port = port

    s.PROMPT = "r\s+>$|\s+> $|\s+#$|\s+# $"

    s.login(hostname,username,password,auto_prompt_reset=False)
    print("Logging into Console Port...")
    s.prompt(timeout=10)
    print ("Good to Go! Press Enter")
    print ()
    s.interact()
    sys.exit()


def main():
    # Print initial menu
    while True:
        first_menu()
        choice = int(input("Enter your Choice: "))
        if choice==1:
            print("THIS DOESN'T WORK YET!!")
            print("TRY AGAIN!!")
        if choice==2:
            host = idf_menu()
            print(host)
            port = int(port_menu())
            print(port)   
            rlogin(host)
        if choice==0:
            print("Whatever. Bye.")
            sys.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    main()
```

Comment: Pass `port` to `rlogin` as an argument, instead of trying to access a nonlocal variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to call the variable port in function "rlogin", but port isn't a global variable. Pass it as an argument to rlogin

```
def rlogin(host, port):
```

ore just leave out the line

> port = port

Comment: It does have to be an argument; as you point out, `port` isn't global, but a local variable to the `main` function. Python is lexically scoped, so `rlogin` cannot refer to a nonlocal variable that isn't defined in the scope where `rlogin` was *defined*.

Comment: Well I think I made it a step further, thank you, I'm getting another error now that does not seem to be at all related to my original question so I think this one is answered :)

The above answer gave me a good thing to look for and I had to also add it under my "def main()" when I call the rlogin function
rlogin(host, port)